# What's the easiest way to get Lisp-Style addition (+ *args) in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, lisp

So I really like this syntax in Lisp:

```
 (+ 1 1 2 3 5 8 13)
 => 33
```

I want to add a list of items in Ruby and would like to approximate this as best as possible.
Right now, my best solution involves an array and the collect/map method.

So:

```
sum = 0; [1,1,2,3,5,8,13].collect { |n| sum += n }
```

BUT...

I would like to add methods to this which could return nil.

```
sum = 0; [1, booking_fee, 8,13].collect { |n| n = 0 if n.nil?; sum += n }
```

And it would be really nice to do this, where all of the lines in the middle refer to methods that may return nil, but I can't exactly build an array in this manner. This is just an idea of what I want my syntax to look like.

```
def total
  Array.new do
    booking_fee
    rental_charges
    internationalization_charges
    discounts
    wild_nights
  end.collect { |n| n = 0 if n.nil?; sum += n }
end
```

Any suggestions before I try to hack away and effectuate Greenspun's Rule? (Programming is indeed a compulsion.

Comment: I always thought a Lisp syntax over Ruby would be awesome. I think that's the kind of thing you're trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- There is already a method `inject` for doing what you want.
- Changing `nil` to a number without affecting a number is easy: use `to_i` (or `to_f` if you are dealing with float).

.

```
[
  booking_fee,
  rental_charges,
  internationalization_charges,
  discounts,
  wild_nights,
].inject(0){|sum, item| sum + item.to_i}
```

Answer (score 10):

I really don't understand your question. If you want a method that works like `+` does in Lisp, i.e. takes an arbitrary number of arguments and is in prefix position rather than infix, that's trivial:

```
def plus(*nums)
  nums.inject(:+)
end

plus 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13 # => 33
```

If you want to get *really* fancy, you could override the unary prefix `+` operator for `Array`s:

```
class Array
  def +@
    inject(:+)
  end
end

+[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13] # => 33
```

**Please don't do that!**

I don't see how the rest of your question is related in any way to a Lisp-style addition operation.

If you want to remove `nil`s from an `Array`, there's `Array#compact` for that.

Comment: Lol just now know unary + can be overloaded too ! Thanks:-)

Comment: @JörgWMittag - Only place I've seen these pre-fix operators was in SICP, so...I assumed it was Lisp style syntax...but I guess Ruby has (some of) it as well! Thanks.

Comment: @texasbruce: You can override all of Ruby's unary prefix operators except for `defined?`. The method names are `+@` (`+`), `-@` (`-`), `!` (for `!` and `not`), `to_proc` (`&`) and `to_ary`/`to_a` (`*` aka *splat*).